# Necessary condition for every irreducible is prime?

Tags: abstract-algebra

The condition that $R$ is a GCD domain is sufficient for every irreducible element to be prime. However, is there a necessary condition?

It does seem to be the case that in an integral domain $R$ for which every element can be factored into irreducibles, $R$ is a UFD iff every irreducible is prime. But without this, is there a nice necessary condition?

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3057093/242) for this and much more.

Comment: Ok so it seems that without the ring being an atomic domain, AP doesn't necessarily have a nice implication?

Comment: An extreme case is when there are no atoms ([antimatter domains](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/96802/242)), so AP holds vacuously, e.g. the ring of all algebraic integers where $\,\alpha = \sqrt\alpha \sqrt\alpha.\ $ But when AP holds and there are atoms then we deduce as usual the uniqueness of products of atoms (but not every element need be such a product).

Comment: "But when AP holds and there are atoms then we deduce as usual the uniqueness of products of atoms." - This follows from AP = PP for atomic a, right? Also this doesn't imply that the ring is UFD? All that it implies is that if an element has a factorization into atoms then the factorization is unique?

Comment: Generally in a domain if an element has a  prime factorization then that is the unique atomic factorization, as the usual proof shows.